# Understanding Threading in Google Cloud DataFlow Workers

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I made a simple program which waits for 60 seconds. I have 300 input elements to process.

Number of threads - Batch - 1 and Streaming - 300 per this document
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#beam-java-sdk

1. In streaming mode - with 1 worker and 300 threads, job should complete in 2 to 3 minutes considering the overhead of spawning workers etc. My understanding is there will be 300 threads for each of 300 input elements and all sleep for 60 seconds and the job should get done. However, the job takes more time to complete.
2. Similarly, in Batch mode with 1 worker (1 Thread)  and 300 input elements, it should take 300 minutes to complete.

Can someone clarify how this happens at worker level ?

Answer (score 1):

There is considerable overhead in starting up and tearing down worker VMs, so it's hard to generalize from a short experiment such as this. In addition, there's not promise that there will be a given number of workers for streaming or batch, as this is an implementation-dependent parameter that my change at any time for any runner (and indeed may even be chosen dynamically).